# How to connect Universal Links to UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, ios-universal-links

> *Disclaimer: I've only been coding in iOS/XCode/Swift for a couple of weeks

I have Universal Links working in that clicking a link outside my app opens up the app and I catching the Url in the AppDelegate class.

So that's all good.

My question is... how do I then redirect to the correct UIViewController AND pass the controller some info from my URL? All Universal Link tutorials stop before they get to that part.

In particular I'm confused about the lifecycles of AppDelegate and how it relates to UIViewController.

My app had two UIViewController sitting under (is this right?) a UINavigationController.

### What I've tried

I have tried handling the url event in AppDelegate, and setting a public property, and then in my ViewController getting access to the AppDelegate. HOWEVER, after the Universal Link is clicked, both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` don't get called again :-/

What's the best way to redirect to a ViewController from AppDelegate? My goal is simply to load the root view controller BUT I need to pass in some data from the URL. How?

Comment: Put some parameters in the url, then in the AppDelegate you can insert the logic to open the right view controller. You can try something like www.example.com?key=parameter

Comment: Thanks! But the question is HOW to I navigate to the ViewComtroller and pass that data. That's the question! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First, Read your URL.
2. Get your parameters from URL
3. Initiate your target controller
4. Set your parameter to that controller
5. Present controller on root view controller

   ```
        let urlString = url.absoluteString
        let queryArray = urlString.componentsSeparatedByString("/")

        if queryArray[2].lowercaseString == "yourQuery" {
            let queryId = Int(queryArray[3])

            if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController != nil {
                self.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            }

            let queryVC = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(QUERY_SCENE) as? QueryViewController
            queryVC?.urlQueryId = queryId!
            self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(queryVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   ```

**Edit:**

1. Push a controller say 'PresentedViewController' on navigation controller and if rootViewController is also navigation controller
2. And on back press on controller 'OnBackPressViewController' present controller 'PresentedViewController'

   ```
        if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController != nil {
            self.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }
        let navController = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController() as? UINavigationController
        let presentedVC = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(PRESENTED_SCENE) as? PresentedViewController
        //Pass parameters to PresentedViewController
        let onBackPressViewController = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(ON_BACK_PRESS_SCENE) as? OnBackPressViewController
        navController!.pushViewController(onBackPressViewController!, animated: true)
        navController!.pushViewController(presentedVC!, animated: true)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

You can update your code according to that. Always remember that you have to present any view controller on rootViewController.

Comment: dude, gonna try this now, but thank you for the thorough explanation! Gonna try it right now.

Comment: Also, it will be more helpful if you update question with what type of controllers you are using or like to present or push

Comment: Thanks Lalit!!! That worked. My bad.... I'm really new to this, I'll add what controllers I'm using.

Comment: if I wasn't using a UINavController then how would it work?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your app architecture. You can definitely assume that the AppDelegate has the reference to the `rootViewController` (`window?.rootViewController`). You should know what's the type of that controller. Then you can access to the other and so on. This question is, anyway, too much generic in my opinion.

Comment: thanks! I guess I can seem how it can seem generic but the maybe that's because I'm so new to it, I need a bit more guidance on how to navigate to the controller. Like... yes, I see I do have access to the root controller... but then how do I navigate to it AND pass it a parameter, know what I mean?

Comment: the RootViewController should be a `UITabBarController` or a `UINavigationController`. Then you can access to the specific controller (by accessing to `viewControllers` array)